# Parent element triggers even with stopPropagation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got an issue concerning event propagation in a table where I got dynamically created elements.

When I click on my `div` "menuBtn" (let's call it the "button"), the `onclick` action occurs.
I need the action not to be executed.

I added `event.stopPropagation();` in my "button" function, but that doesn't change anything.

See below snippet for working example:

```js
// Open menu function
function open_menu(elm) {
  elm.css({
    "top": PosY,
    "left": PosX
  }).fadeIn(200);
}

// Mouse move
var PosX, PosY;
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  PosX = e.pageX;
  PosY = e.pageY;
});

// If document is clicked somewhere else than the menu, close menu
$(document).on("mousedown", function(e) {
  $(".menu").fadeOut(100);
});

// I bind my function on click, on the menuBtn.
// I am doing it this way because .menuBtn are created dynamically
$('table').on('click', '.menuBtn', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation(); // Why it isn't working ?
  open_menu($(this).closest('tr').find(".menu"));
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: inherit;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-bottom: 800px;
}

tr {
  background-color: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
}

td {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 10px;
  height: 64px;
}

.menuBtn {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 100px;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border: 2px solid #888;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr onclick="console.log('I do not want to see that.')">
        <td>
          <p>Element</p>
          <div class='menuBtn' title='Open menu'>[ ↓ ]</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <ul class="menu">
            <p>menu of “Element”</p>
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Please, enlighten me.

Comment: How the button should not trigger the event if you binded the event to the button? Who’s gonna fire the event then?

Comment: It has to propagate....you are delegating the event listener to the `<table>`. Stop mixing inline `onclick` and unobtrusive methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding a delegated event to the `<table>` which would listen the event and check if the triggering element for this event matches `.menuBtn`. So the event bound straight to the `<tr>` is nothing to do with the button click event.

This snippet is the same as yours. You can see that the `tr` event triggered before the `.menuBtn` event. Both events are just like parallel lines in this case.

```js
// Open menu function
function open_menu(elm) {
  elm.css({
    "top": PosY,
    "left": PosX
  }).fadeIn(200);
}

// Mouse move
var PosX, PosY;
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  PosX = e.pageX;
  PosY = e.pageY;
});

// If document is clicked somewhere else than the menu, close menu
$(document).on("mousedown", function(e) {
  $(".menu").fadeOut(100);
});

$('tr').on('click', function(){
  console.log('tr clicked')
})

// I bind my function on click, on the menuBtn.
// I am doing it this way because .menuBtn are created dynamically
$('table').on('click', '.menuBtn', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation(); // Why it isn't working ?
  console.log('btn clicked')
  open_menu($(this).closest('tr').find(".menu"));
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: inherit;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-bottom: 800px;
}

tr {
  background-color: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
}

td {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 10px;
  height: 64px;
}

.menuBtn {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 100px;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border: 2px solid #888;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Element</p>
          <div class='menuBtn' title='Open menu'>[ ↓ ]</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <ul class="menu">
            <p>menu of “Element”</p>
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

To show that the `tr` event will not be propagated by click `.menuBtn`, here's a demo:

```js
// Open menu function
function open_menu(elm) {
  elm.css({
    "top": PosY,
    "left": PosX
  }).fadeIn(200);
}

// Mouse move
var PosX, PosY;
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  PosX = e.pageX;
  PosY = e.pageY;
});

// If document is clicked somewhere else than the menu, close menu
$(document).on("mousedown", function(e) {
  $(".menu").fadeOut(100);
});

$('tr').on('click', function(){
  console.log('tr clicked')
})

// added for demonstration
$('table').on('click', function(){
  console.log('table clicked')
})

// I bind my function on click, on the menuBtn.
// I am doing it this way because .menuBtn are created dynamically
$('table').on('click', '.menuBtn', function(event) {
  //event.stopPropagation(); // Why it isn't working ?
  console.log('btn clicked')
  open_menu($(this).closest('tr').find(".menu"));
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: inherit;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-bottom: 800px;
}

tr {
  background-color: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
}

td {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 10px;
  height: 64px;
}

.menuBtn {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 100px;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border: 2px solid #888;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Element</p>
          <div class='menuBtn' title='Open menu'>[ ↓ ]</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <ul class="menu">
            <p>menu of “Element”</p>
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

This one binding a delegated event, showing that `.menuBtn` event triggered first. Cause it propagates from `.menuBtn` to the `table`.

```js
// Open menu function
function open_menu(elm) {
  elm.css({
    "top": PosY,
    "left": PosX
  }).fadeIn(200);
}

// Mouse move
var PosX, PosY;
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  PosX = e.pageX;
  PosY = e.pageY;
});

// If document is clicked somewhere else than the menu, close menu
$(document).on("mousedown", function(e) {
  $(".menu").fadeOut(100);
});

$('table').on('click', 'tr', function(){
  console.log('tr clicked')
})

// added for demonstration
$('table').on('click', function(){
  console.log('table clicked')
})

// I bind my function on click, on the menuBtn.
// I am doing it this way because .menuBtn are created dynamically
$('table').on('click', '.menuBtn', function(event) {
  // event.stopPropagation(); // Why it isn't working ?
  console.log('btn clicked')
  open_menu($(this).closest('tr').find(".menu"));
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: inherit;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-bottom: 800px;
}

tr {
  background-color: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
}

td {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 10px;
  height: 64px;
}

.menuBtn {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 100px;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border: 2px solid #888;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Element</p>
          <div class='menuBtn' title='Open menu'>[ ↓ ]</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <ul class="menu">
            <p>menu of “Element”</p>
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

So if you want to prevent this issue, just use a delegated event to `<tr>` as well.

```js
// Open menu function
function open_menu(elm) {
  elm.css({
    "top": PosY,
    "left": PosX
  }).fadeIn(200);
}

// Mouse move
var PosX, PosY;
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  PosX = e.pageX;
  PosY = e.pageY;
});

// If document is clicked somewhere else than the menu, close menu
$(document).on("mousedown", function(e) {
  $(".menu").fadeOut(100);
});

$('table').on('click', 'tr', function(){
  console.log('I do not want to see that.')
})

// I bind my function on click, on the menuBtn.
// I am doing it this way because .menuBtn are created dynamically
$('table').on('click', '.menuBtn', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation(); // Why it isn't working ?
  open_menu($(this).closest('tr').find(".menu"));
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: inherit;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-bottom: 800px;
}

tr {
  background-color: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
}

td {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 10px;
  height: 64px;
}

.menuBtn {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 100px;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border: 2px solid #888;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Element</p>
          <div class='menuBtn' title='Open menu'>[ ↓ ]</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <ul class="menu">
            <p>menu of “Element”</p>
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

If there's anything wrong, misleading or not clear, please feel free to let me know or edit the post.